# Binding DataGridView to List<Object[]> (List of Array of Objects)

Tags: c#, datagridview, binding

I want to display a large amount of data in a datagridview (or anything practically similar); this data is currently a List i.e. an array of objects (most of which can sensibly be cast as strings) stored in a List<>.

Do I need to create Binding(s), linking each array position to a column, and each list item to a row?

Basically I'm just trying to replicate displaying a DataTable in DataGridView, where the DataTable happens to be held as a List

I can't establish how a Binding object or property can be manipulated to achieve this.

Comment: Why `Object` vs the actual type?  Most users wont find `Object` properties very interesting.

Comment: I'm wanting to use different types for elements within the same list item instance, so assumed i'd need to leave them as objects without being specific to achieve that.

Comment: I usually just put the list into a datatable.  Create a datatable with columns that match your list.  DataTable dt = new DataTable(); dt.Columns.Add("ColA", typeof(int));dt.Rows.Add(myList[0]);

Comment: Thanks for the comment jdweng. Given that i'm using quite a lot of data, I'd been led to believe the overheads from using a fully fledged DataTable unnecessarily might slow the thing down. I had previously implemented via a DT and am halfway through converting to List<> ;)